# Inline if-statement with multiple OR's

Tags: apex, visualforce, inline-visualforce

How do I deal with a inline if-statement with multiple OR conditions? (if I'm wording that correctly)

e.g.

The page I'm working on basically needs to check the specific page and specific field and then output a different text based on the salesforce status.

So if the status in salesforce is 'Listed on eBay', 'Listed on the web', 'Listed on etc.', 'Located in Store', I want it to just output 'For Sale' on my visualforce page.

First we have this for:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!item[field]}" rendered="{!not((pageName == 'thispage' || pageName == 'anotherpage' || pageName == 'againanotherpage') && field == 'Item_Status__c')}" />
```

Then below that ( a really long inline conditional with parts removed ):

```
{!IF(pageName == 'itemsforsale' && field == 'Item_Status__c', IF(item[field] == ‘sf-field1’ || item[field] == ‘sf-field2’ || item[field] == ‘sf-field3’ || item[field] == ‘sf-field4’ || item[field] == ‘sf-field5’ || item[field] == ‘sf-field6’, ‘ACTUAL OUTPUT’, [false statement goes here], '')), '')}
```

How do I make the code above without having to do so many OR statements?

Comment: I would consider moving logic from VF to my apex code by adding wrapper class for sObject with extra render parameters, which are evaluated in apex code, and checked only in Visualforce

Comment: Why do you want to have these many ORs there? You should use apex, declare a boolean flag, say 'Redered', and then apply all the logic of OR/AND there. Just check that boolean flag here. Simple. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction to this question was, "this sounds like it should be a formula field". That would certainly work, and follows the "Clicks, not code" philosophy.

However, that doesn't simplify the logic at all. The complexity is simply moved to another location.

That said, there is one way that I can think of to reduce the number of logical OR's. You can create a getter method (in a custom controller or a controller extension), and use a set and the `contains()` method.

The `contains()` method is logically equivalent to a string of `||`.

An example

```
public MyControllerExtension{
    MyObject__c myRec;

    Set<String> forSaleStrings = new Set<String>{
        'Listed on eBay', 'Listed on the web', 'Listed on etc...', 'Located in Store'
    };

    // Omitting the constructor that takes an ApexPages.StandardController
    // You'd also need to fetch or query for the record that you're working on
    //   to ensure that you have access to Item_Status__c

    public Boolean getIsForSale(){
        return forSaleStrings.contains(myRec.Item_Status__c);
    }
}
```

Your visualforce would then change to

```
{!IF(pageName == 'itemsforsale' && field == 'Item_Status__c', IF(isForSale, ‘ACTUAL OUTPUT’, [false statement goes here]), ''), '')}
```

There's a good chance that you could replace that entire inline IF, but this is about as far as I can go with the information/code that you've provided.